# MVC 3 IList<T> Model Properties NULL on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, viewmodel, ilist

I'll let the code do the talking here, I have something like this:

```
class Problem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Symptom> Symptoms { get; set; }
}

class Symptom
{
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a modal that allows users to add a list of symptoms on my view.  Each symptom being added produces an INPUT that looks like this (where N is the index):

```
<input type="text" name="Symptom[N].Name" value="@Model.Symptom[N].Name">
<input type="text" name="Symptom[N].Category" value="@Model.Symptom[N].Category">
```

Once I POST the data to my controller, the model contains a valid list of **Symptom** (if I add 3, my Product.Symptom list has 3 entities) and the [Comments] of each symptom has persisted, but the [Category] property of each is NULL.  What am I doing wrong here?  I've tried numerous things but I still end up with NULL as the [Category] for each.

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First with Fluent API developing in MVC 3 using Razor syntax.

Comment: what does your action method look like?

Comment: The usual: if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(model) } otherwise add to repository and redirect.  The added symptoms do persist (including category names) on post back (if a validation error occurs) which is very odd!

Comment: no, the method signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text"
    name="Symptom[N].Category.Name"
    value="@Model.Symptom[N].Category.Name">
```

What I think is happening is that it's trying to bind a `string` to a `Category` which is invalid. If you want to map the text to the `Name` property on the `Category` class, you will need to specify it one level deeper.

Comment: The model binder doesn't know how to map "Symptom[N].Category" to a Category. You'll need to use the method Hunter suggested, and that is to output the property of the category.  If your category entity only has a single property, why break it out in to its own model?

Comment: @Splash-X I'm guessing there's more to that form/class, but I may be wrong. `Category` might be shared across many `Problem` items, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, hunter is right that class needs to be a separate entity to prevent duplication and mis-spelling.  I know I could just have a hard-coded IList<string> but the table that Category represents is used across more applications so they need to be similar.  OK, I've tried Symptom[N].Category.Name but I'm still getting NULL in the Name property - is it possible that what I'm trying to do can't be done and I need to either a) have a string CategoryName which is a foreign key to Category entity or b) create a custom model binder that will know what to do?

Comment: You know what - the reason hunter's suggestion didn't work is because I'm an idiot!  Brilliant, have it working now - thanks very much!